# Print users to console excluding those with default avatars Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I go about printing to console a list of users in my server, excluding those who have the default/null avatar? My current code looks like this, but does not work. It print's the list of users, but it does not exclude those with default avatar. This is using the Discord.py rewrite.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
token = ""
prefix = "?"

import discord
import asyncio
import codecs
import sys
import io
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

print ("waiting")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, self_bot=True)
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("users with avatars")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def userlist(ctx):
    for user in list(ctx.message.guild.members):
        if user.avatar == None:
            pass
        else:
            for user in list(ctx.message.guild.members):
                print (user.name+"#"+user.discriminator)

bot.run(token, bot=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User`s also have a [`User.default_avatar`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.User.default_avatar) attribute.  If you compare that to `User.avatar`, you should be able to filter out the users for which those match.

```
@bot.command()
async def userlist(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if user.avater != user.default_avater:
            print (user.name+"#"+user.discriminator)
```

This is assuming that your real problem isn't that you're looping through all the members again inside the `else`.  Try this variation of your solution:

```
@bot.command()
async def userlist(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if user.avatar:
            print (user.name+"#"+user.discriminator)
```

Comment: Btw you can also print the user so you don't need the `user.name+"#"+user.discriminator`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `user.avatar` does not return `None` when user's avatar is blank.
Try to find a value that `user.avatar` returns when user's avatar is blank.

```
for user in list(ctx.message.gild.members):
    print(user.name + " = " + user.avatar)
```